# USDX before and after EURO

Tags: eurodollars

I'm googling all over the internet but seems no luck. Just curious, if anyone knows, what did the formula look like for USDX before euro was adopted? And on which day did ICE change the formula ? Jan 1st, 1999 or sometime in 2002?
Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The current weights are:

EUR: 57.6%;

JPY 13.6%;

GBP: 11.9%;

CAD: 9.1%;

SEK: 4.2%;

CHF: 3.6%.

(Observe that this list still does not include some major trading partners of the US such as China, Brazil, and South Korea.)

Since the inception in March 1973 and until January 1999, the weights of the Euro's precursors were:

West German Deutschemark DEM: 20.8%

French Franc FRF: 13.1%

Italian Lira ITL: 9.0%

Dutch Guilder NLG: 8.3%

Belgian Franc BEF: 6.4%

the weights of currencies other than the EUR were the same as now.

By the way, the index is administered by the Fed, not by ICE.

Comment: A real shortcoming of the DX Dollar Index is that the weights are so out of date (As Dimitri noted) and too Europe centered. The Federal Reserve Trade Weighted Dollar Index (Broad) is more representative, but unfortunately it has no tradable counterpart AFAIK. See this article https://cernocapital.com/us-dollar-index-fit-purpose

Comment: Much appreciated, Dimitri.  really curious wonder if there was a jump of USDX from Dec 31st, 1998 to Jan 1st, 1999. FXs of old european currencies to new Euros were fixed, but the new Euro replaces more European countries' currencies than the ones in the USDX.

Comment: My please. I don't have Bloomberg Anywhere to check this, but I googled and found this nice graph https://www.macrotrends.net/1329/us-dollar-index-historical-chart of USDX since 1973. I don't see a big jump in 1999, when the pre-Euro currencies got replaced by an equivalent amount of EUR.

Comment: For completeness, I believe https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/DTWEXBGS is the USTWBROA Index that noob2 mentioned - published weekly, the weights are revised annually.